# Canvas function result not shown until the while loop is active

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to draw a figure on canvas, and the calls to the canvas are inside the while loop. The issue is that the results are not shown (drawn) on canvas until the whole loop is done. The code example is attached. If unclear I can post the entire code.

```
while (remainingLetters > 0 && numOfTries > 0) {
z++;
ctx.fillRect(10*z,10*z, 50, 50);
}
```

My expected result is that this will draw one rectangle each time it loops, and will offset it in x and y direction by 10 pixels. That does happen indeed, but only after the loop is done, how I know this, is because this is a hangman game and it has some other check and calls to prompt() and alert() functions. These shapes are drawn only after the game (while loop) ends.

Comment: please add your code or at least a link to a codepen or jsfiddle or whatever

Comment: JavaScript is synchronous and a loop does not give any time to the browser to update the rendering. You will need to change things to call `fillRect` only once at a time, using `requestAnimationFrame` or some other kind of timer

Comment: @enxaneta here is a fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/twistedwire/4n5kdyb0/
Sorry for some words and outputs being in Croatian, but it shouldn't be too hard to understand the logic since most of my functions are in English.

Comment: @BaliBalo Thank you for the info. I'll see if I can make a workaround and post my results then.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really know much about the canvas but have you tried with setinterval() instead of while(), or maybe requestAnimationFrame()

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. I will probably redo the game with JQuery and keypress method, but I will still give some other workarounds a shot since this is a quite nice of a learning challenge.